# Mapping from $(Z_q)^m$ to $(Z_q)^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

If we define a mapping f from $(Z_q)^m$ to $(Z_q)^n$ such that $f_A(x)=Ax$ where A is a fixed matrix of required order and $m>n$. What is the condition on A in $(Z_q)^{nm}$ required, so that $f$ is an onto or surjection?

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is a surjection iff $A$ has maximal rank $n$. This can be decided by row reducing $A$.

This holds for every linear transformation over a field. It is not particular to $\mathbb Z_q$.